# Access button in div popup watir web-driver

Tags: ruby, webdriver, watir

I am trying to retrieve, modify, and reinsert some text in a pop up dialog using watir web-driver. All was going swimmingly until I tried to find a way to click the "Save Book Info" button pictured here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGdln.png

However I am unable to find the button. To access the pop up box I gather all the links with the correct name into an array:

```
    @browser.imgs.each do |img| #The links are imgs
        if img.title.include?('Edit/Delete Book')
            @books << img
        end
    end
```

From there I can access the links with `@books[index].click`. I am able to access and edit the text_fields with:

```
url = @browser.text_field(:name=>'url').value
... do stuff with url ..
@browser.text_field(:name=>'url').set url
```

But when I try and find the "Close" button I only get the buttons that are on the main page. After many headaches I managed to find the title of the window I want to work with using `@browser.div(:class=>'dijitDialogTitleBar').title`, which returns `"Edit Book"`. Success! No. I still can't figure out how to access the buttons on that popup!

If anyone could help me with this I would be most grateful. This is my first time using Watir so it's probably a simple answer...

If more information is needed I'd be happy to supply it. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Here is the html for the button:

```
<span id="dijit_form_Button_2_label" 
class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" 
dojoattachpoint="containerNode">Save Book Info</span>
```

Comment: Can you obtain the HTML for the Save Book Info and Cancel buttons (e.g. using firebug or similar tool)?

Comment: @orde Yes I added the html for the button.

Comment: Looks like @Justin Ko has your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a span tag that is styled to be looked like a button. You need to access it is a span instead of a button.

Try:

```
@browser.span(:text => 'Save Book Info').click
```